# how to store user clicks on two different parts of jsp page into mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

My jsp page has two parts, left and right.After user log in their name will be displayed and also if they click on left or right will be shown.

At the left part, without user interaction data should be displayed in a table and at right side by choosing a name from a drop down list and clicking the button the data will be displayed in a table. I want to store the number of clicks after they close their browser.

Would you please provide some guidance, should I pass each var to a new servlet and update MySQL table? and the other problem is that when a user clicks on button since it will be post to servlet class their name and counts on left part will be removed. I think I should change the style of programming but I couldn't figure it out how to do it.

This is what I have done :

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="second.jsp">
        <center>
         <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User id</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </center>
    </form>
</body>
```

second.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
String user = request.getParameter("uname"); 

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db",
        "root", "pass");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where uemail='" + user + "' ");
if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("uname", user);
    out.println("welcome " + user);
} else {

     int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into users (uemail) values ('" + user + "')");
        if (i > 0) {
            session.setAttribute("uname", user);
            out.println("welcome " + user);
        }
 }
%>

<div style="width:100%;" >
<div style="float:left; width:60%;" >

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
 user="root"  password="pass"/>

 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="resultt">
 SELECT a,b,c,d from table;
 </sql:query>
 <table  width="70%" onclick='lcounters()'>
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${resultt.rows}">
 <tr>
 <td><a href="${row.a}" target="blank"><font  size="5">${row.d}</font> </a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><font color="green" size="4"><c:out value=" ${row.b}"/></font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td ><c:out value=" ${row.c}"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 &nbsp;
 </td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 <script> var lclicks = 0;
 function lcounters() {
 clicks += 1;
 document.getElementById("lclicks").innerHTML = lclicks;

 };</script>

 <p>Clicks: <a id="lclicks">0</a></p>
 </table>
 </div>

 <div style="float:right; width:40%; ">

 <form action="ActionServlet" method="post">
 <table >   
 <tr> <td> Names:</td>
 <td>   
 <select name="names">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="bbb">bbb</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="submit"  name="jdbc_query"  value="Show" />  </td>
</tr>
<script> var rclicks = 0;
function rcounters() {
 rclicks += 1;
 document.getElementById("rclicks").innerHTML = rclicks ;

};</script>
<p>Clicks: <a id="rclicks">0</a></p> 
</table>
<c:if test="${result != null}">

<table border="1" width="100%"  onclick='rcounter()'>
          <tr>
          <th>first</th> 
          <th>second</th>
          <th>third</th>

        </tr>
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
 <tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.u}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.v}"/></td>
<td>  <a href="${row.w}"> <font color="green"> ${row.x} </font>    </a><br>${row.y}   </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach> 
</table>
</c:if>
</div>
 </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

servlet class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result;
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.ResultSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet {


@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String out = "\n";
    String cname = request.getParameter("names");
    MysqlDataSource ds = null;
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    try {

    ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    ds.setUser("root");
    ds.setPassword("pass");
    connect = ds.getConnection();
    statement = connect.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT u,v,x,w,y FROM table2 where name= ? "  ;
    PreparedStatement ps1 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    ps1.setString(1, cname);
    ResultSet resultSet = ps1.executeQuery();
    Result result = ResultSupport.toResult(resultSet);
    request.setAttribute("result", result);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

   } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.getErrorCode(); }
        try { connect.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.getErrorCode(); }
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very unstable environment!

wonder why you need to count the clicks, but if it's a business essential, so you need to think about desktop applications, with web you cannot have it 100% stable and working.

BUt if you insist to fix the problem, I suggest have a WebSocket, and pass the clicks every x seconds to the server.

Also try to use connection pools and prepared statements, your db connectivity state is the worst one right now.